# CGImageRef to CGContextRef memory issue

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm writing an application for iPhones.

One function is to allow the user to take picture and then apply auto corrections using a lut. I get the asset from the camera roll, create a `CGImageRef` then draw into a `CGContextRef`. Using the `CGContextRef`, I access the pixel data and apply the lut. All is well except on devices with lower memory capabilities like iPhone 4's and iPad Mini's. Having two huge blocks of data in memory, `CGImageRef` and `CGContextRef` will some times cause the application to jettison. I'm wondering if there is a better, less memory intensive way of doing this.

Comment: are you working on the full-sized image? You may think of using a screen-size scaled version.

Comment: I need to correct to full size image. I am saving it to the clouds for others to download.